# How can I display an object in angular without quotes on the keys

Tags: angularjs

I built a simple form in angular that takes user inputs and sets them as the value to an object. At the end I need to be able to copy the generated data from the front end. But displaying the data adds quotes to object keys. Is there a way around this?

Example:

```
$scope.finalData = {
  name: 'john doe',
  age: '30',
  gender: 'male'
}
```

If I use `{{finalData}}` in the front end,  it shows up like this:

```
 {"name":"john doe", "age": "30", "gender":"male"}
```

How can I get it to show up like this:

```
{name:"john doe", age: "30", gender:"male"}
```

Comment: @Jax please don't recommend jQuery solutions to angular problems....

Comment: You are correct, the other question is based on json strings, so I didn't find it in my search. The top answer looks like it may solve my issue though, thanks!

Comment: Going to mark this as duplicate. I get that a jquery approach isn't ideal within angular. Although the question I'm being pointed to by @jax is jquery related, the top answer is to use regex not jquery, so I think it's a reasonable approach, and it solves the issue.

Comment: @Claies as far as I see the Q in the other SO relates to jquery however the answer I was referring to uses Regular Expressions to solve the problem. It is a bit confusing alright. But thought the Regex approach was a valid one.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to do this is with `ng-repeat`.  you can iterate over the `key/value` pairs in the object, like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in finalData">
  {{key}}:  {{value}}
</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:CR2TtS1zz9wFGgsl5z2c?p=prev

It's worth noting that Angular isn't "inserting quotes"; rather, Angular is passing the object through `JSON.stringify()` when you pass it as the sole parameter in an expression.

Comment: This is an excellent approach that makes perfect sense to me, but I had not considered. I think it may not be the best solution for me though because there may be situations where the key's value may be another object. Also thanks for explaining the JSON.stringify() step it's getting passed through, this is very useful information.

Comment: true, this doesn't work for nested/compound objects, but really this kind of output should only be for debugging;  when outputting for production use, you should generally be directly referencing the properties.....